# Referrer traffic

Tags: referrer

I noticed repeat visits to my site from various websites, all located in the Ukraine. I looked at the source of the pages and see no links to neither my domain nor IP.

I am wondering of the origin of this traffic. Hopefully there's no malicious intent. Is there a way to research it deeper?

Comment: May be some advertisements are leading users of those website to your website?

Comment: I am not advertising anywhere. And why all from the same country? Most of the sites are in Russian... and totally unrelated. Mine is all in English and quite specialized.

Comment: How trusted is your referrer data? Are you using analytics to track such data? SiteCatalyst/Google analytics?

Comment: Yes, it is an analytics tool. But I don't just rely on it. Plugging IP usually resolves in a referrer from that country.

Answer (score 3):

It's just [referrer spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam).